# Any consideration of moving QGIS project file to SQLITE form XML?

Tags: qgis, xml, sqlite

Just curious, has anyone ever proposed storing the ".qgs" project file in SQLITE instead of XML?  Seems like it might be faster, easier to parse, and you could hide the changes behind an API.  But I know I am not volunteering... So, if anyone has heard such a discussion, please post the links or comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there seems to be no actual problem to be solved and it is more of an “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” type of question - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

I would not know of such considerations.

I wonder if performance of reading the project file is really something worth tuning, as most likely any performance impact rather is caused by other things like loading layers from providers.

Is there any problem with parsing that needs to be fixed?

I wonder what you are referring to with "hide changes behind an API".

If you think that this is worth considering, please raise this issue on the QGIS developer mailing list and make sure that you precisely describe what the problems with the current format are and what could be improved by switching the format.

Comment: I don't think it is worth submitting a request; I only ask out of curiosity, because I think a relational configuration is more flexible and robust than an XML system, in general (I am fine with QGIS as a user, however).  "Hide behind an API": if there is a get_config(key) function, for example, you can swap in an SQL query for an XML query without exposing the change to the calling scope.  SQLITE is just as user-readable as the current XML, too, since it is open.  Oh -- sometimes map composer can get slow, and I wonder if it is rewriting the XML file, slower than an insert, I bet.

Comment: So basically you are asking for an abstraction layer (API) to make the switch of formats easier? Just because in your original question it sounded like an advantage of sqlite. And concerning user-readable... Well, open the sqlite db in a text editor and see if you can read it. For the slow map composer, please [open an issue](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) and list the evidence that suggests rewriting the XML is the cause.